# ng serve hangs at 69% when ran within a gulp task

Tags: angular, gulp

I have the following task:

```
import {exec} from 'child_process'

gulp.task('start:angular', () => {
  const ng = exec('ng serve')

  ng.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
  ng.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
})
```

which I run in my console like this: `gulp start:angular`

This will get stuck every single time at 69% at 578/581 modules but the last module varies from time to time.

However when I run this manually, i.e: `ng serve`, I can run my angular app jsut as well.

I need the gulp task, there is no way around that so please don't sugest using another thing, it's not up to me.

`gulp: ^3.9.1`
 I tried with angular `6.0.1` and `6.0.3`.

Thanks in advance!